# Pivotviewer and Bing Map Integration

Tags: silverlight, pivotviewer

I am trying to get a Bing map integrated into a PivotViewer - has anyone been successful?

I have got them together but it is not as "smooth" or polished as I'd like it to be.

Things that are wrong :
1. The map does not drag when inserted into the PivotViewer.
2. The map is hidden by the Facet Filter Panel.

[image: How it Looks]

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [PivotViewer Lessons](http://pivotviewerlessons.codeplex.com) to see an example of how to remove the filter pane.  As far as Bing integration, [Xper360](http://xpert360.wordpress.com) has done some work in that area and might be able to help you out.